# Why does this function return undefined but console.logs the correct answer?

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
 const getMonthlyPriceFromData = (planName) => {
    planTypeData.map((item) => {
      if (item.name === planName) {
console.log(item.monthlyFee, 'fee')
        return item.monthlyFee;
      }
      return null;
    });
  };
```

when I console.log(item.monthyFee) it returns the correct answer but when I call

console.log(getMonthlyPriceFromData('Free')) it returns undefined?

Comment: `planTypeData.map(....)` ----> `return planTypeData.map(...)`. Looking at your code, you should use the `find` method instead of the `map` method

Answer (score 4):

There is no actual `return` statement inside your function:

```
  const getMonthlyPriceFromData = (planName) => {
    return planTypeData.map((item) => {
      if (item.name === planName) {
console.log(item.monthlyFee, 'fee')
        return item.monthlyFee;
      }
      return null;
    });
  };
```

Or use [short arrow form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). This way you can omit the `return` keyword, **only** if you skip the curly braces too `{`:

```
  const getMonthlyPriceFromData = (planName) => planTypeData.map((item) => {
      if (item.name === planName) {
console.log(item.monthlyFee, 'fee')
        return item.monthlyFee;
      }
      return null;
    })
```

**EDIT:**

OP seems to want only one item retuned from the array and for that [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would be a better approach:

```
const getMonthlyPriceFromData = (planName) => planTypeData.find((item) => {       
if (item.name === planName) { console.log(item.monthlyFee, 'fee')         
return true;       }       
return false;     })
```

Comment: why does this return [null, null, '323'], I just want it to return 323

Comment: Because you are returning `null` outside the `if`. If you want to do that you will have to use `filter()`. `map` returns exactly the same number of array elements and basically just transforms the array

Comment: If you only want the first item you will need `find()`.  
`const getMonthlyPriceFromData = (planName) => planTypeData.find((item) => {
      if (item.name === planName) {
console.log(item.monthlyFee, 'fee')
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "return" before "planTypeData.map", like this:

```
 const getMonthlyPriceFromData = (planName) => {
     return planTypeData.map((item) => {
         if (item.name === planName) {
             return item.monthlyFee;
         }
         return null;
     });
 };


 console.log(getMonthlyPriceFromData('Free'))
```

Then it should work!